# Visual Source Safe Version 8

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

My issue is that when I check a project out of SS I sometimes do not get the latest version of the project, and when I check a project into SS the .frx files are corrupt.

Answer (score 3):

Are you tied to SS?  Can you not use a more modern repository?  Subversion would be a good start.  Getting that started is very easy to do, a lot easier than I think people think.

If not, then you have to run a tool to find out what the corruption is and then try to clean it or reset it.   You may also check the server time as sometimes that caused problems.  The server time should be the same as the development machines I believe.

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't have a solution, but I think you are beating a dead horse.

Source (Un)Safe isn't good, and never was, but the problems with it rarely exhibits themselves until it has been used for a while.

Trust me when I say it will be better if you find a different system to keep your source code in.

It's like saying that "My 25 year old rusty car isn't starting every morning, how can I fix it?" and the answer to that is of course to ditch it and get a new car.

Answer (score 1):

An .frx? Thats a VB6 form resource file right?

Vss often had trouble with these files due to the way it uses hashing to determine if the file had changed.  Switch your VSS settings to use Modfied date instead.

**Edit**: one caveat, VSS doesn't understand daylight savings hence every six months it thinks all you files are ought of date and fetches the lot again.  Doesn't do much harm but is really annoying.

Comment: Yes, .frx are VB6 form resource files. Thanks I'll look into your solution.